# Why HttpRequest returns NULL while reading for second time?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httprequest, restlet

I am creating webservices in **Java using RESTlet API**. I am using 2.0 stable version.

In this I am getting **NullPointerException** error while reading the request for second time.

I have applied the Filter on webservices for security purpose. In filter class I am checking the request contains the expected parameters. If it is successful then the call is made to webservice.

While processing in the webservice I am getting the **NULL** in request. Following is my Filter class -

```
public class MyFilter extends Filter {

    public MyFilter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {

        int result = STOP;
        try
        {
                String requestSt = request.getEntityAsText();
                // Check for validation 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

When I read the request for second time it returns **NULL**. Even when I just write -

```
System.out.println(request.getEntityAsText());
```

before -

```
String requestSt = request.getEntityAsText();
```

then also it gives me **NullPointerException** for the line **String requestSt = ....**

So please provide me the solution to read the request for multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the incoming request entity to ensure its content isn't lost after reading it a first time. For this purpose, you can leverage the org.restlet.engine.io.BufferingRepresentation class.

This line should do it:

```
request.setEntity(new BufferingRepresentation(request.getEntity());
```

You might need to update to version 2.1 which is the current stable version.

Comment: Its pleasure to be answered by the Father of Restlet, the Restlet Guru. I'll switch to version 2.1.

Comment: Do you have a solution that will work for Restlet 2.0? We are using Activiti which uses Restlet 2.0.

Comment: It seems you can use a StringRepresentation instead in 2.0.